# Testing whether the Euler Totient of a number equals to certain value

Tags: algorithm-design, prime-numbers, complexity

I have solved a problem in [Project Euler.](https://projecteuler.net/problem=248) My solution was based on the finding the all numbers whose Euler Totient value equals to $13!$

However, while I was working on the problem, I thought that: "Can I find an algorithm that tests whether the Euler Totient of a number equals to $13!$ ?" I know that finding $\phi(n)$ is as hard as [factoring $n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3274/how-hard-is-it-to-compute-the-euler-totient-function/3275#3275). On the other hand, we can easily test whether a specific number is a factor or not.

We have probabalistic primality tests such as: Fermat's, Euler's, Miller-Rabin etc. We can test the primality of a number efficiently. Can we use same approach to test "Is $\phi(n)$ equals to specific number?"

We know that $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1\pmod n$ if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ by Euler's Theorem. Can we use this congruence to test probabilistically whether the Euler Totient of a number equals to certain value like in primality tests mentality?

Or more generally, What is the most efficient way of testing whether the Euler Totient of a number equals to certain value?

Comment: Oops, I misread that as 13 exclamation point instead of 13 factorial, which makes the problem quite trivial. Nevertheless, you want a fast test whether $\varphi(n)=m$. May we assume that $n$ may be arbitrarily wild, but $m$ is nice and (as is the case with $m=13!$) we know the prime factorization of $m$? In that case, there is a simple upper bound for $n$ and we can easily find all prime factors of $n$ (namely, primes dividing $m$, and primes dividing some $d+1$ where $d\mid m$).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen this still can turn to be an answer..

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Actually my question is more general. In 13! case, there is no problem to factor n whose Euler Totient equals 13! as you say. However, I'dont remember the exact count but there are potential prime factors for n more than 400. Even if I know the all potential factors, factoring n and computing phi(n) is not efficient as I would like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though it is not completely straightforward.

There is a tighter form of Euler's theorem for composite numbers that says that $a^{\lambda(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n$ for $(a,n)=1$ where $\lambda(n)$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). The Carmichael function always divides $\phi(n)$ but (for example) for odd composite numbers it is always less than $\phi(n)$. Therefore simply testing to see if $13!$ is a multiple of the order of random residues (and there there exist random residues where the order is exactly 13!) won't allow us to distinguish numbers where $\lambda(n)=13!$ but $\phi(n)>13!$.

However, a you note we can compute $\phi(n)$ if we can factor $n$ and it turns out that the numbers where $\phi(n)=13!$ are very easy to factor using a variant of [Pollard's $p-1$ algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm). Given a candidate non-prime $n$, we pick a random $a$ (we can check if $(a,n)=1$ and divide out a GCD is it is), raise it to the power $13!/1024$ modulo $n$ and there is a very good chance that the answer is not $\pm 1$ (we can even raise the odds by choosing $a$ with Jacobi symbol -1 mod $n$). Writing the answer as $x$ we compute $x^2, x^4, \ldots , x^{1024}\mod n$ by squaring. Eventually the sequence becomes all 1s (the last value is certainly 1) and the previous value is either -1 or a non-trivial square root of unity, say $y$ such that $y^2\equiv 1\pmod n$. In this case $\mathrm{GCD}(n,y\pm1)$ splits $n$ into two smaller numbers. The method recurses and I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: FYI. This answer is hard to follow...